# Adding a submodule with a specific SHA1 to an existing git repo

Tags: git, git-submodules

This has been asked quite a few times over the years, but never seen an actual answer.

I would like to add some open source code to my existing project as a submodule, but I can only use a specific commit SHA1.

I have set up an example to demonstrate the problem.

So, my main project is:

```
https://github.com/BitvuLtd/myProj
```

As you can see, there is a sub module in this project that points to:

```
https://github.com/BitvuLtd/strangersPro/tree/bd06980e0d711348bc7831f6421b3c5b27948781
```

I would like to point that to the next commit up the line:

`https://github.com/BitvuLtd/strangersPro/tree/1463dd07645ce4e0450aabaa952b4c657d`

I don't want the most up-to-date commit as it is incompatible.

The closest I've got is being able to checkout the correct commit is in a separate cloned copy of the submodule using:

```
git checkout 1463dd07645ce4e0450aabaa952b4c657d16da39
```

But if I do that in the submodule directory of the main project, it get:

```
fatal: reference is not a tree: 1463dd07645ce4e0450aabaa952b4c657d16da39
```

Comment: Did you pull the submodule before checking out a commit? You need the commit to be in your local repo to check it out.

Answer (score 7):

#### TL;DR: you need to update your gitlink

To do this, you need to update the submodule's Git repository to the desired commit (which is a commit, not a tree), and then run `git add` and `git commit` in the superproject:

```
$ cd strangersPro
$ git checkout 1463dd07645ce4e0450aabaa952b4c657d16da39
```

then go back to the superproject and `git add strangersPro` and commit:

```
$ cd ..
$ git add strangersPro
$ git commit
```

#### Details

Definition: a *submodule* is a Git repository (not a very useful definition, but not exactly *wrong*).  The term "submodule" gets used in several different ways.  Typically "submodule" means "a Git repository being used as a submodule", which is a terrible definition since it kind of [begs the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question), but let's go with that anyway. :-)

Definition: a *superproject* is a Git repository that has at least one submodule in it.

Definition: a *gitlink* is a reference to another Git repository.  Such a reference consists of two items:

- something by which we name the specific other Git repository, and
- the hash ID of a *specific commit* that (we assume) exists in that other Git repository.

#### What you want to do is to add or update a gitlink

To add a *new* gitlink to a Git repository, so that this Git repository *becomes* a superproject containing a submodule, you must at some point (once only per submodule) run `git submodule add`.  This creates or updates a translation table.  We need this table because the name stored in the gitlink is a *path name*, such as `strangersPro`.

The (file) name of this table is `.gitmodules`, and it contains several lines per submodule.

In this particular case, that's already been done: there is a `.gitmodules` file that has these lines in it:

```
[submodule "strangersPro"]
    path = strangersPro
    url = https://github.com/BitvuLtd/strangersPro
```

Now that we have this file with this entry in it, we can create one of these special gitlink entries.  The gitlink comes in two parts.  One looks like a file or directory/folder name—in this case, `strangersPro`.  The other is a commit hash ID.

*The path name, `strangersPro`, is easy to see.  The commit hash ID is not as easy to see.*  But the gitlink entry provides *both* at the same time.  Meanwhile the `.gitmodules` file provides the way for your Git to know to clone a *separate* Git repository, i.e., the submodule: the `.gitmodules` file says that to work with `strangersPro`, your Git should clone *another* repository—the submodule itself—under the `strangersPro` directory.

Now that your superproject has a second Git repository inside it (in `strangersPro`), your superproject's Git runs another `git checkout` inside the submodule.  This second `git checkout` uses the commit hash in the gitlink to check out the one specific commit.

#### Updating a gitlink

Now that you have an existing gitlink, your task becomes: *change the hash ID*.

You do this much the same way you change any file in a repository: by making a *new commit* after running `git add`.  That is, the gitlink is *checked in* to every commit in the same way that any other file, like `README.md`, is checked in to every commit.

Hash IDs, though, are just big nonsense numbers, and you can't edit the "gitlink file" directly (it's saved only in the superproject's index / staging-area, not a regular work-tree file).  Hence, to update the gitlink, you must first navigate into the submodule itself:

```
$ cd strangersPro
```

This submodule is itself a Git repository, just like any other Git repository.  That means you can run `git checkout` and `git status` and `git branch` and `git add` and `git commit` and so on.  But all you want to do here is check out a new specific commit.  You will need the big nonsense hash ID.  Fortunately you provided this above: it's `1463dd07645ce4e0450aabaa952b4c657d16da39`.

```
$ git checkout 1463dd07645ce4e0450aabaa952b4c657d16da39
```

Now your submodule has a detached HEAD at this commit (instead of the old detached HEAD it had before).

Now you navigate *out* of the submodule repository, back to the superproject.  You can now `git add` the submodule *path*.  Your superproject git will read the current commit hash ID out of the submodule and add that to your superproject's index:

```
$ cd ..
$ git add strangersPro
```

Now you are finally ready to commit in the superproject, recording the new hash ID under the existing name.