# ignore directory which has .git subdirectory?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'd like to ignore directories if it has it's own `.git` directory.

```
project-root
  - sub-project1 (with `.git`)
  - sub-project2 (with `.git`)
  - other files
```

How can I tell(`.gitignore`) to ignore all the directories with its own `.git` such as sub-project1/2 ?

Comment: Make them subprojects.

Comment: One by one, there is no automatic way.

Comment: You probably want subtrees https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a script which would:

- find an .git subfolder
- take their parent folder ([`dirname`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname))
- add it to `.gitignore` (if not already present)
- remove it from the index (in case it would already recorded by the parent repo as a [gitlink entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44730384/6309))